# Possible to make vc-dir aware of (hg) subrepo changes?

Tags: vc, mercurial

vc-dir works really well for most of my needs, as I use both hg and svn repositories. But most of the hg repos I work with have subrepositories. I typically use vc-dir buffers for each of the subrepos and the top level repo.

The problem is that a change in one of the subrepos does not get registered by the top level repo, so I am unable to (detect or) commit the change from emacs.

How can I make the top-level hg repo aware of subrepos?